# how to display toolbox on the left side of window of Visual Studio Express for windows phone 7 development?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I am new to Visual Studio development.

Occasionally I hide the toolbox on the left side of window of Visual Studio Express.  But then, sometimes, I would like to use it.

How does one reactivate and display it?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut I use, although that may because I have `Resharper` installed - otherwise <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>.

From the menu: **View** -> **Toolbox**.

You can easily view/change key bindings using **Tools** -> **Options Environment**->**Keyboard**.  It has a convenient UI where you can enter a word, and it shows you what key bindings include that word, including `View.Toolbox`.

You might want to browse through the [online MSDN documentation on getting started with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/toolbox).

Comment: "Ctrl - Alt - X" works for me, standard Visual Studio Professional 2017.

Answer (score 6):

Just select from the Visual Studio menu View- > ToolBox .

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio Express 2013 for web it's hidden away in View > Other Windows > Toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you can just do 'Window -> Reset Window Layout', and that'll work :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with Blend for Visual Studio 2015. The Toolbox would just not appear anymore. This turns out to be because **Blend is not Visual Studio**!

(You can edit your code in Blend and build and run it... It certainly seems like Visual Studio, but it isn't. I'm not sure what the purpose of Blend is...)

You can tell you are in Blend if the task bar icon has big "B" in it. To switch from Blend to Visual Studio, go to `View`-> `Edit in Visual Studio...`. It will open up another application that looks just like Blend, except the Solution Explorer is on the right instead of the left, and now you have a toolbox...

Answer (score 0):

Go to the toolbar and Click View -> Toolbox and you will get the toolbox in left side of the screen.

[image: View -> Toolbox]