# Visual Studio 2017 : Windows Form designer not appear

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm developing a windows form designer.
I'm not able to view form designer to add components.
How can I solve my problem?
resx is present. I reset also devenv
simone

Comment: You can take a look to this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974115/how-to-display-toolbox-on-the-left-side-of-window-of-visual-studio-express-for-w), I think that it's the same issue

Comment: Alright. But what does appear when you double click on the form? Any messages in the Output window? Did you edit the form's cs file outside of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Shift+F7 press
- in the Solution Explorer right click on the form and click "View Designer" option

Answer (score -1):

@ Simnoe : I have face the same issue with VS 2017, but I was able to solve it. What you got to do is right click on your form, for example if your form name is "Form1.cs". Right click on it and you'll see an option called "Include in project", just click on it, this should solve your problem.